# Identity Server 4 - Resource Owner Password Grant and Google Authentication

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I have an application that currently uses the resource owner password grant type to allow users to log in via a single page application. The identity server is hosted in the same project as the Web API currently. However, we would like to add the ability for a user to register / log in using their Google account. Currently, the user data is stored in tables and managed by ASP.NET Core Identity.

Is there a way to have both the resource owner password grant type available in the application for users who are 'local' but also enable third party authentication via Google? Currently, we hit the Identity Server token endpoint with a username and password and store the token in the browser. It's then passed to any endpoint that requires authorization. Would this same flow still work when integrating Google authentication and retrieving the Google token?

Comment: hey did you get this working? If so how? I am trying to do the same thing but not sure what's the api endpoint for triggering the external authentication (e.g. google).

Comment: I am stuck here. @stt106 Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I never did get this working. We ended going a different direction by chance. It's been a while since I posted this question, but I wouldn't use the resource owner grant type if I could avoid it. I'd set up an entirely seperate identity server and enable the implicit flow or authorization code flow and allow my users to sign into the identity server. Then I would integrate the third party providers I needed. I would still be unsure how to connect the third party accounts to my custom user's though, the best way at least.

Comment: @Singularity222 I found the solution.

Comment: Follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62198723/9522887

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the credit goes to **Behrooz Dalvandi** for [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/securing-net-core-web-api-identityserver4-using-owner-dalvandi-1/?trk=mp-author-card) amazing post.

The solution to this problem is to create a custom grant and implement IExtensionGrantValidator.

```
public class GoogleGrant : IExtensionGrantValidator
{
    private readonly IGoogleService _googleService;
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;

    public GoogleGrant(IGoogleService googleService, IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _googleService = googleService;
        _accountService = accountService;
    }
    public string GrantType
    {
        get
        {
            return "google_auth";
        }
    }

    public async Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context)
    {
        var userToken = context.Request.Raw.Get("id_token");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userToken))
        {
            //You may want to add some claims here.
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenErrors.InvalidGrant, null);
            return;
        }
        //Validate ID token
        GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload idTokenData = await _googleService.ParseGoogleIdToken(userToken);

        if (idTokenData != null)
        {
            //Get user from the database.
            ApplicationUser user = await _accountService.FindByEmail(idTokenData.Email);

            if(user != null)
            {
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(user.Id, "google");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Configure this validator in the Startup

```
            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.Ids)
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.Apis)
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
            .AddResourceOwnerValidator<CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>()
            .AddExtensionGrantValidator<GoogleGrant>();//Custom validator.
```

And last but not the least.
Add below code in the config file. Notice the 'google_auth' grant type.

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "resourceownerclient",

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials.Append("google_auth").ToList(),
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,
                IdentityTokenLifetime = 3600,
                UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
                SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 30,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
                RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.OneTimeOnly,
                AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                Enabled = true,
                ClientSecrets=  new List<Secret> { new Secret("dataEventRecordsSecret".Sha256()) },
                AllowedScopes = {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                    "api1"
                }
            }
```